# phpmyadmain config is not working

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I just installed pma in my mac, and it works fine with the localhost db.
When i tried to access the remote db, I add a server in the setup page, and i choose the remote db as my default db. But when i go back to the main panel of the pma, i cannot find the remote db anywhere(no sever list either
), I'm still working on the local db. So i go back to the file system and checked the config.inc.php, the config file looks all fine. Any suggestion?

this is my config.inc.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.4.14.1 setup script
 * Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 16:47:13 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: RDS test [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'RDS test';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3306;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'test';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'testtest';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '55faee8e5e0965.84622566';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

Comment: not sure but did you try to delete all phpmyadmin cookies

Answer (score 1):

go to http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/setup to configure phpmyadmin, without creating "config.inc.php"